# Funções MAX e MIN no CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3

Estou tentando realizar uma busca no banco de dados que retorne o menor e o maior valor do campo 'hora' (time) utilizando o seguinte código no CakePHP 3:

```
$pedidos = TableRegistry::get('Pedidos');
$hora_max = $pedidos->find('list', array('fields' => array('MAX(hora)  AS 'hora_maxima')));
$hora_minima = $pedidos->find('list', array('fields' => array('MIN(hora)  AS 'hora_minima')));
debug($hora_maxima);
```

Entretando ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando superficialmente e considerando a mensagem de erro,

```
syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
```

Tem uma aspa a mais:

```
'MAX(hora)  AS 'hora_maxima'
```

Corrija removendo a aspa do meio:

```
'MAX(hora)  AS hora_maxima'
```

Exemplo:

```
$hora_max = $pedidos->find('list', array('fields' => array('MAX(hora)  AS hora_maxima')));
```

Note que o mesmo acontece na montagem do MIN():

```
'MIN(hora)  AS 'hora_minima'
               /\
              /  \
               ||
               ||
```

Comment: Daniel Omine muito obrigado por sua ajuda. Fico muito feliz em saber que temos uma comunidade tão unida. Espero poder em breve estar contribuindo também com a comunidade.
Mais uma vez, muito obrigado.